# Visual programming with Blender Python

Tags: python

Does anyone know if there is some sort of visual programming software for Blender?
I know there is one called "visual bpy". I [watched a demonstration of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DKxgw24u0o). It looks quite promising and should save us a lot of time when writing a GUI in Blender.
Unfortunately, I can't find link to obtain this software even though I've been searching for it diligently.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The download link is in the video description of the demonstration. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DKxgw24u0o

Comment: a simple youtube or google [search](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=visual+bpy+blender&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) could have also yielded an answer.

Comment: I 've did this search over and over and overtime. I wouldn't have posted this without doing any effort!!!!!

Comment: HI Aldrik, thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I am in the region that can't let me see the youtube. If you can post the actual link(but not the blender file of the rig) for the program, that will be very kind of you.

Comment: @Patrick Here is the link Aldrik was referring to: http://www.mediafire.com/download/s2vvlqofv3heqt6/VisualBPY.zip

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct [download link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/s2vvlqofv3heqt6/VisualBPY.zip) for the script. It was in the description of the demo… there is also a small [youtube playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8A1DD070211FCEE7) dedicated to it and the rig used is available on [BlendSwap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/50469).

Comment: CharlesL, you are great!

Comment: Hi CharlesL, not sure you tried it or not. This verison can't let us your the buttons. It prompted "Button features are not available for this version".

Comment: Hmmm... that's weird. That was the version he linked to in the description.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit